# How inject @Any Singletons

Tags: java

I have problem with inject singletons to Instance. I want to inject all singletons which implements interface Inter, I want to take value from class annotation. How I can do that. My solution not working :(

**Interface:**

```
public interface Inter {
    String getString();
}
```

**Annotation:**

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    public @interface IConf {
        String fileName();
    }
```

**Class which implements interface**

```
@Singleton
@IConf(fileName = "Config.xml")
public class ConfObjt implements Inter{

    public String getString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Sing {

    @Inject @Any
    Instance<Inter> beans;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("metoda init");
        for(Inter inter : beans) {
            Class<?> clazz = inter.getClass();
            IConf ano = clazz.getAnnotation(IConf.class);
            System.out.println(ano.fileName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Spring as dependency management framework?

Comment: no, I don't.   Only clear java ee

Comment: Do you have beans.xml configuration? if yes, please share it.

Comment: Annotation singleton used from javax or ejb package?

Comment: no, I don't have bean.xml, in Main class: javax,ejb.Singleton but in ConfObjt : javax.inject.Singleton

Comment: What CDI framework do you use in your project?

Comment: project is deployed on Wildfly 10, and default framework